# Run all scripts in a sub-directory

Tags: security, bash, shell, git

When `git` runs my `post-receive` hook, I'd like it to run all the scripts in the subdirectory `post-receive.d`.

My script is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
DIR="$( dirname "$SOURCE" )"

for SCRIPT in $DIR/post-receive.d/*
do
  if [ -f "$SCRIPT" -a -x "$SCRIPT" ] 
  then
    "$SCRIPT"
  fi
done
```

Source: https://github.com/alexchamberlain/githooks/blob/master/post-receive

Is this secure? Reliable?

I can foresee one problem. The hook supplies data using `stdin`, which should be copied to each subscript. I'm pretty sure this isn't happening at the moment. Any ideas?

Comment: `test -x "$file"` or `[[ -x "$file" ]]` is the only test you need; a file doesn't need to be readable to be executable.

Answer (score 2):

```
for SCRIPT in $DIR/post-receive.d/*
```

You might want to limit that to only `*.sh` pattern, just for clarity.

Personally I'm a fan of the one-line-style, but that's personal preference:

```
for ITEM in SET; do
if [ CONDITION ]; then
```

And yes, input from `stdin` is at the moment ignored completely by your script. Reading from `stdin` can be done via the `read` command, like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

# This whill be our input variable
input=""

# Read the first line without adding
# a new line to the start.
read input

# Start reading from stdin
while read line; do
    # Concate the input into our variable
    input=$input"\n"$line
done

# Echo it...what else?
echo $input
```

After doing that you can pipe the variable into the scripts like this:

```
echo $INPUT | "$SCRIPT"
```

*One word of warning*: I'm not sure if this is BASH only or cross-shell compatible.

Comment: Use More Quotes™ and watch out for newlines - `printf %s "$input" | "$SCRIPT"`. Your `while` loop will drop the last line of input if it's not followed by a newline and treats backslashes specially - `while IFS=$'\n' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do`